# Codename One: Annotation Processing

Tags: java, codenameone, netbeans-8

I have a Codename One project on Netbeans using their plugin.

Is there a way to make it work? I enabled it in project's settings and still doesn't show in final jar.

The annotations are in the libraries of the project. and I can see it being done in the output:

```
warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_6' from annotation processor 'org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.ServiceProviderProcessor' less than -source '1.8'
```

I used instructions here: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/annotations-lombok.html

**Update:**
I thought it was clear but seems it's not. All this is using Netbean's [Lookup](http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqLookup). Let's say I have one jar as project dependency with one interface in it, let's say ITest. Also a class implementing the interface, for example:

```
@ServiceProvider(service=ITest.class)
public class Test implements ITest{
..
}
```

So in the Codenamone Project I call it like this:

```
Lookup.getDefault().lookupAll(ITest.class);
```

But it come up empty. I know the system works as it does in other projects, just porting it to Codename one. Seems like it is not seeing the annotations in the dependencies.

Comment: It's unclear exactly what problem you are facing. Can you explain it further? What is the problem you are facing? What is the *minimal* code required to re-create the issue?

Comment: Updated as requested.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that will work and I'm pretty curious about it myself. Make sure you created a Java 8 version of the project and you are running on top of Java 8 to get started.

In the past things like this were done using bytecode manipulation e.g. see [this code](https://github.com/shannah/cn1-mirah-json-macros) from the [work done by Steve](http://www.codenameone.com/blog/json-to-pojo-mapping.html).

Comment: it works from within the source itself. I see the services being generated but not from the dependencies. I guess I'll have to duplicate functionality just to get it working

Comment: We don't support project dependencies. We have the cn1lib mechanism. Keep in mind that if you manipulate NetBeans we can't take this into the device build so a hack you did might work on the simulator but might not work for Android/iOS etc.

Comment: I see. Sadly I had to stop development due to the framework I was using needs java.net packages not included on mobile it seems. So I'll have to address that part first.

Comment: You can adapt that code to use our networking/socket API's. If you need help in porting that we'd be happy to help

Comment: I'm more than interested. How can we get started?

Comment: What exactly do you need to port?

Comment: It is Marauroa engine: https://sourceforge.net/p/arianne/marauroa/ci/master/tree/ I'm afraid it's too big of a task.

Comment: Yes that would require some work. I can help you with small tips but this is a bit outside of our domain of focus.